# Make a fixed div stay fixed horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is code that fixes a div to the top of the screen when the user scrolls to it.

However, on my browsers, if the user scrolls left or right, the bar stays fixed to the top but scrolls along. I wanted the bar to stay put, with the content it's over.

Here is the [jfidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFq2k/608/)

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                    $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                    $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                    $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                    $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: What browsers are you using? In the latest Chrome, it stays fixed no matter which way you scroll.

Comment: If you use `position: fixed;` then that bar will stay in the viewport no matter what direction you may scroll even left to right.

Comment: latest firefox on mac, stays fixed for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part is `left:-$(window).scrollLeft()`

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/6HJyg/)

```
$(function () {
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#stickyheader').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0px',
                left: -$(window).scrollLeft()
            });
            $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $('#stickyheader').css({
                position: 'static',
                top: '0px'
            });
            $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```